# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm having a base64String in my response and trying to convert that base64 to image. I have used the Uint8List class https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html. but cannot reference my converted base64 to Image.memory.

```
class Data {
  String sId;
  String name;
  String category;
  String image;
  int iV;
  var decoded;
  Uint8List bytes ;

  Data({this.sId, this.name, this.category, this.image, this.iV, this.bytes});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    name = json['name'];
    category = json['category'];
    image = json['image'];
    iV = json['__v'];
 // decoded = Base64Decoder().convert(image);
   bytes = base64.decode(image);
  }
```

```
Container(     
margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          height: 140.0,
                                          child:Image.memory('${data.bytes}'),
                                        ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSEt6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
Container(     
margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          height: 140.0,
                                          child:Image.memory(data.bytes),
                                        ),
```